# Linking event handler not fired when app is in background

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am implementing logging in using Facebook, Twitter, etc.. When the user clicks on the icon, safari opens, the user logs in, and then the webpage redirects to `appname://login`.

I followed this article https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e, and my code looks like the following:

```
componentDidMount(){
    Linking.getInitialURL()
    .then((url) => {
      if (url) {
        // Alert.alert('GET INIT URL','initial url  ' + url)
        this.resetStackToProperRoute(url)
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {})
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  handleOpenURL = (event) => {
    console.log('event: ' + event);
  }
```

The problem is nothing gets printed on the console. I think the problem is that the handler is not fired when the app comes from the background. Is there a way around it?

thanks

Comment: Where is the code for the icon that the user clicks on?

Comment: @whs.bsmith `index.ios.js` at the moment